# Get a loading image to fade out and have the actual image fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to show a loading image before the actual image gets loaded. How can I get the loading image to fade out and the actual image to fade in smoothly once the actual image is loaded? The `setTimeout()` is for demo purposes.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95rpu029/11/

**HTML**

```
<article class="project">
    <img width="375" height="375" src="http://i.imgur.com/lJpvTU3.gif" class="attachment-home-thumb" data-mainSrc="http://dummyimage.com/375x375/000/fff">
    <img width="375" height="375" src="http://i.imgur.com/lJpvTU3.gif" class="attachment-home-thumb" data-mainSrc="http://dummyimage.com/375x375/f00/fff">
    <img width="375" height="375" src="http://i.imgur.com/lJpvTU3.gif" class="attachment-home-thumb" data-mainSrc="http://dummyimage.com/375x375/0f0/fff">
</article>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var imgs = $("article.project img.attachment-home-thumb");
        $.each(imgs, function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var im = new Image();
            im.onload = function () {
                var theImage = $this;
                theImage[0].src = im.src;
                $this.show('fast');
            };
            im.src = $this.data("mainsrc");
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

**CSS**

```
article.project {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 2%;
    max-width: 375px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 23%;
}
article.project img {
    display: inline-block;float:left;
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/95rpu029/12/

You can fadeOut the image, change its source and then fade it back in:

```
 im.onload = function () {
     var theImage = $this;
     theImage.fadeOut("fast", function(){
         theImage[0].src = im.src;
         theImage.fadeIn("fast");
     });
 };
```